# Ionic 5 Ion-Slider Bound Options Not Affecting the Component

Tags: ionic-framework, swiper.js, ionic5

I'm using Ionic 5 and wanted to customize the `ion-slides` bound `options`, but the object literal being bound to the component doesn't change anything in the UI.

I created an example [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-4kwczs?file=src/app/app.component.ts) so the `options` not working is replicated. You can see that even adding `initialSlide` doesn't seem to work, which is the example from their docs - [Ionic Slides](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides#usage).  I tried a bunch of [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/api/) parameters as well with no luck. In a separate [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-4kwczs?file=src/app/app.component.ts) using vanilla Swiper I can see what should be happening.

I'm sure it's probably something minor that I'm doing wrong. Can anyone see why the options aren't taking effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
public slideOptions : {
  initialSlide: 2, 
  slidesPerView: 2,
  centeredSlides: true,
  spaceBetween: 30,
};
```

You want:

```
public slideOptions = {
  initialSlide: 2, 
  slidesPerView: 2,
  centeredSlides: true,
  spaceBetween: 30,
};
```

I tested transpiling both examples above at [typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) and the current code only transpiles into `slideOptions;` instead of the object you want.

Comment: OMG thank you sooooo needed the second set of eyes!!!

Comment: Hahaha I didn't notice at all that I wasn't an assignment operator between the member variable and the object literal.  Goofed!

Comment: Totally get it. I was 99% positive that's what had happened. I just didn't want to make any assumptions. Happens to all of us. Happy coding